# App does not support launch on secondary displays Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this toast message on the emulator and device when trying to launch a new activity from my initial one on a secondary display. From my understanding this is a newer feature with Android O. I've searched thoroughly but could not find this problem anywhere else thus I am here. I understand this can be done with presentations but I need to getting it working with activities. Could someone tell me why this occurs?

Answer (score 3):

Android does support launching an Activity to a secondary display via code (initiating via an adb command not required). Here is an example:

```
  ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
  options.setLaunchDisplayId(d.getDisplayId());
  Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  secondIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivity(secondIntent, options.toBundle());
```

If you are seeing a toast message with the error that it is not supported then in your `AndroidManifest.xml` add the `resizeableActivity="true"` property to your activity like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Android O does not support start activity on the second display except using the "am stack start  " command, do you use this to launch activity to the second display?

From the android source code, the warning toast is shown when we tried to put a non-resizeable task on a secondary display with config different from global config.

Maybe you can use the "am task resizeable  [0|1|2|3]" commands to make the task resizeable.